# iphone dynamicly call same view (using storyboard?)

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, xcode4.3

I'm new to iphone dev. My app Design has 3 views. One start screen. Then you press a button and you go to a table view. The table view will decide if it goes to another same table view with other data (and how many levels down ) according to an xml file. Then it will go to a view that shows details. For example it might go like:

Main Screen -> table view -> detail view
Main Screen -> Table view -> table view -> table view -> detail view etc.

So I want to be able when a cell is chosen in the table view then (if this is what the xml describes) call a same view (same view Controller and code). And when the xml describes so go to detail view.

Can this be done using storyboards? If I want to use ios 4.3 how can I do it?

I'm using latest (4.3) xCode on Lion. Also note that this xcode does not have a template for a Navigation Based app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen till now, I can't dynamically call the same view from storyboards. So I implemented a navigation controller using the following tutorial and it works like a charm for me!

```
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews
```